# IPython's magic %paste silently fails with ← symbol

Tags: python, ipython, copy-paste, paste, ipython-magic

IPython's magic %paste silently ignored everything in my clipboard under certain circumstances. The causal agent: a commented ← symbol. This is automatically generated in Google docs by typing <-- and space.

Comparison of outcomes, when copy-pasting with and without a commented ← symbol:

```
print 'foo' # ←
```

[image]

```
print 'foo' #
```

[image]

Notice how in the first case (involving ←) IPython simply ignored the content of %paste as if I had an empty clipboard.

**Firstly**, would anyone who has more knowledge of the code underlying IPython's magic %paste be able to explain why this silent error occurs?

**Secondly**, what other characters might cause this? What is the unifying property across such characters?

**Versions:**

IPython 0.13.2

Python 2.6.6

**Character Encoding:**

en_GB.UTF-8

**Terminal:**

Bash Xterm

Comment: What kind of terminal are you using, and what is its character encoding?

Comment: Btw, I'm unable to reproduce the problem using IPython 2.0.0, Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu gnome terminal, UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @unutbu interesting, character encoding: en_GB.UTF-8, I am using the standard bash terminal or Xterm (depending on what you mean by type)